# Is there a way to remove the background window that pops up when calling askopenfilename()?

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

When I call the basic command:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

filename = askopenfilename()
```

A little window pops up behind the selector screen.

[image]

Is there a way to remove this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It pops up because you need at least a "root" window for each tkinter application. In your case, you aren't creating any root window explicitly, so `askopenfilename` creates it automatically for you. One solution would be to create the root window explicitly and then hide it, something as follows

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import Tk

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
```